# Relevel/Change reference factor in mixed model analysis

Tags: r, mixed-models

Here's my data in R software (from excel):

[data from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W6yt.png)

I am doing a mixed model like this:

#confiance

anova(lm(Confiance ~ ActeurConfiance+(1 | ID)))

résultatconfiance <- lm(Confiance ~ ActeurConfiance+(1 | ID))

anova(résultatconfiance)

summary(résultatconfiance)

The reference category is Gouvernement, like this:
[results mixedmodel with gouvernement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7TMF.png)

**My problem is:** I want the Industrie to be the reference category (right now it is gouvernement), and I tried the functions relevel and fct_revel and also factor and it doesn't work. Any ideas for the line to run in my specific case? I'm new to R and this is quite a challenge for me.

Thank you,
Marie

Comment: `relevel` is a fine way to do it. Rather than showing your model, it would be more useful if you showed us the relevel code that didn't work. `résultatconfiance$ActeurConfiance = relevel(résultatconfiance$ActeurConfiance, ref = "Industrie")` should work just fine assuming everything is spelled correctly.

Comment: Ah, so you have an ordered factor! We need to fix it to be a regular factor. First run `résultatconfiance$ActeurConfiance = factor(résultatconfiance$ActeurConfiance)` then run `résultatconfiance$ActeurConfiance = relevel(résultatconfiance$ActeurConfiance, ref = "Industrie")`. The error message makes it clear what the problem is. (Run both those lines **before** you run you `anova()` or `lm()`. In the code in your comment you run the model first, then try to fix the data. You want to fix the data first, then run the model.)